# WordPress post count per (day/month/year) since blog began

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to echo the number of posts per month since the blog began, and for months where there was no posts echo '0'.

This is the output I want:

January 1, February 3, March 8, April 3, ...

Any help would be great. Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [wp_count_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) built in function. If you would like a tool to help with exposing built in wordpress functions, try [webmatrix](http://Microsoft.com/web/webmatrix)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) then loop through the posts and count the results for each time range.

Also, you might want to take a look at the [time parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) for WP_Query, if you need to count the results for a specific time range.

You might also want to try posting on [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Varun has an idea here (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60859/post-count-per-day-month-year-since-blog-began), and it prints a count per month. What I need it to do is where that month is 0 posts, print 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Even this (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22461/how-to-display-posts-month-by-month) would also be useful if I can get it to print out the zero results.